# Populate header with multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html

I have this multi-dimensional array in JavaScript and i'm trying to populate a header in HTML with it i want to populate this header so that all the first name is printed out separately in the header. Is there an easy way to accomplish this because i'm not sure how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var personArr = [];
    var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:21};
    var person2 = {firstName:"Paul", lastName:"Logan", age:22};
    var person3 = {firstName:"Sean", lastName:"Kim", age:32};
    var person4 = {firstName:"Ken", lastName:"Chow", age:12};
    
    personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
    console.log(personArr);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: just google, foreach javascript and echo html javascript ..

Comment: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will be of help. Google as well btw...

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript implementation

We can iterate over personArr array to get firstName and then will store firstName inside h6 tag

```js
var personArr = [];
    var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:21};
    var person2 = {firstName:"Paul", lastName:"Logan", age:22};
    var person3 = {firstName:"Sean", lastName:"Kim", age:32};
    var person4 = {firstName:"Ken", lastName:"Chow", age:12};
    
    personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
    
var content = "";
for(var i=0;i<personArr.length;i++)
{ 
  content +="<h6>"+personArr[i].firstName+"</h6>"; 
}

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML  = content ;
```

```html
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <div id='content'></div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs changed to pure JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Add Jquery to your file and go over each array element with forEach. Afterwards, you can add the .text element for each individual object key

```js
    <html>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var personArr = [];
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:21};
var person2 = {firstName:"Paul", lastName:"Logan", age:22};
var person3 = {firstName:"Sean", lastName:"Kim", age:32};
var person4 = {firstName:"Ken", lastName:"Chow", age:12};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

$(document).ready(() => {
  var p = 1;
  personArr.forEach(function(element) {
    $("#"+p).text(element.firstName);
    p+=1;
  });
})

</script>
<body>
  <h6 id="1"></h6>
  <h6 id="2"></h6>
  <h6 id="3"></h6>
  <h6 id="4"></h6>
</body>
</html>
```

You could do something like this!

Comment: you should add an explanation to avoid a copy/paste generation of developers

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: jquery isn't always the best solution, it's another loaded resource, and for a one time use, a waste .. just use pure js